# What do I need to import from Twitter's bootstrap to extend the .panel class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Given the following .scss file

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap';                                                                                                                               

.item1 {                                                                                                                                                                 
  @extend .row;                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                        
.item2 {                                                                                                                                                                 
  @extend .panel;
}
```

Why does extending `.row` work but extending `.panel` fail compilation?

Error output:

```
Syntax error: ".item2" failed to @extend ".panel".                                                                                                                       
          The selector ".panel" was not found.                                                                                                                       
          Use "@extend .panel !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory to me:  the class you're trying to extend doesn't exist.

Comment: @cimmanon That's what I assumed also. Updated question title to more accurately represent question...

Comment: @danwoods, what version of Bootstrap are you using? I think `panel` was added in 3.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban That seemed to fix it. Downloaded the latest version from github, and it worked! Thanks. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: @danwoods, sometimes the answer lies in the docs. Unfortunately the best documentation I can find for the SASS variables is the [LESS docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less), then I translate in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.panel` exists in [Boostrap 3.0 components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels), but not for [Boostrap 2.3](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html). Check your version and update your `@extend`s!